# Magento 2.0 Library

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento2 on server,and started developing the module,everything was working fine till I referred `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager` in the code to get the object.

The issue is there is no `Magento\Framework` library in Magento lib folder. Please can anyone tell me,How to install `Magento\Framework` libraries in magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install Magento2?

In case you cloned the git repository, the Magento Framework is under lib/internal. When installed via composer, the Framework should be under vendor/magento/framework.

If it is not, you might have to run `composer install` first in the Magento root dir to install all dependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot..that helped..actually m trying to get helper class using ObjectManager.But now I am getting an error :

 Class Magento\Core\Model\factory\Helper does not exist.

Please ,can you tell me where I am getting wrong.?It will be a great help!!

Comment: what helper should this be? Magento\Core\Model\factory\Helper? There is no Core Module anymore. To get any class you can just inject it in the constructor. More about Magento2 DI can be read here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html